# A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/tools/lint/model/LintModelModuleLoaderProvider

Tags: java, flutter, dart, mobile, cross-platform

I just created a new flutter application and did not change anything. When I try to run it, this error pops up

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/tools/lint/model/LintModelModuleLoaderProvider
```

I have never experienced this error until I updated my flutter to 2.5.1

Comment: Try a) flutter pub get, b) flutter create c) flutter clean and step a.